# Phonegap smooth scrolling on Android

Tags: android, cordova, scroll

Can we somehow make scrolling smoother on Android?
It works great on the iPad and iPhone, but any, even the most powerful Android devices, it is not a smooth, slow down. I use the version cli-5.1.1 and plugins crosswalk. This is particularly evident where there is a picture, as you scroll through them a little twitch.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Scrolling is smooth in native apps if you use right classes (like RecyclerView) and ViewHolder, convertview

Comment: Infact I have seen it at par with iOs.

Comment: I'm not talking about the native scrolling

Answer (score 1):

Please consult this url: https://quickleft.com/blog/4-steps-to-minimizing-rendering-issues-in-cordova-applications/

You should apply the following styles to the scrolled elements:

```
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
```

Comment: This answer should be accepted, it made a huge difference in my scrolling